# Laravel event when the publishing date is came

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-events

I'm using Laravel but I searched for the appropriate way to do ..

We write articles in our website and give them a publishing date.

Those articles won't display in our website before the publishing date.

Is there any way by using Laravel or another way, to do something immediately after the publishing is done, ex. sending an email

Comment: *"Is there any way [...]"* Yes, of course there is. What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what can I do? I tried to use cronjob every minute, but I want the process fired immediately after publishing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send a job to your queue and delay it until the post is published.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#delayed-dispatching

Edited example from documentation:

```
ProcessPodcast::dispatch($podcast)->delay($article->published_at);
```

Comment: Thanks, Can the delay wait for weeks, or just few hours? at all, I opened the laravel queues page to learn more

Comment: It can wait for as long as you want. The delay sets a timestamp when the job should be executed.